# как определить количество дней в месяце, григорианского и юлианского календарей, и вывести нужное количество option в select'е

Tags: javascript

есть два селекта с числами месяца,

в каждом выводится по 31 опции,

как создать функцию и добавить в скрипт?,

с учётом того что вып списки служат для выбора даты по разным системам летоисчесления, один для григорианского календаря, второй для юлианского, а также учесть что надо выбирать даты из разных эр, как н.э,так и до н.э., или проще сказать что нулевого года нету, и высокосными являются не 0,4,8... а 1,5,9 и т.д.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Конвертирование григорианского/юлианского календаря</title>
        <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Old+Standard+TT:wght@700&family=Tinos:ital@1&display=swap');
        a { text-decoration: none; color: hsl(210,100%,50%); }
        form { margin: 0; }
        div { border: 1px solid hsl(240,100%,50%); color: hsl(240,100%,50%); font: 16px 'Old Standard TT', serif; padding: 5px 10px; overflow: auto; min-width: 504px; margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
        span { font-family: 'Tinos', serif; }
        h1 { margin: 0; color: hsl(0,0%,100%); font: 16px 'Old Standard TT', serif; text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), 1px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%), 1px 0px hsl(240,100%,50%), 0px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px 0px hsl(240,100%,50%), 0px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%); -webkit-animation: h-pulsare 1.35s linear infinite; animation: h-pulsare 1.35s linear infinite; }
        button { font: 16px 'Old Standard TT', serif; background: hsl(240,100%,97%); color: hsl(240,100%,50%); border: 1px solid hsl(240,100%,50%); padding: 5px 25px; }
        #b { margin: 0; }
        #gDay {  }
        #gMonth {  }
        #gYear { width: 56px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; }
        #gEra {  }
        #jwDay {  }
        #jDay {  }
        #jMonth {  }
        #jYear { width: 56px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; }
        #jEra {  }
        #gwDay option, #gDay, #gMonth, #gYear, #gEra, #jwDay, #jDay, #jMonth, #jYear, #jEra { background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 93%); color: hsl(240,100%,50%); }
        select, input#gYear, input#jYear, input { background: hsl(240,100%,97%); color: hsl(240,100%,50%); border: 1px solid hsl(240,100%,50%); font: 16px 'Old Standard TT', serif; line-height: 1; margin: 5px 3px; }
        input { background: hsl(240,100%,97%); color: hsl(240,100%,50%); border: 1px solid hsl(240,100%,50%); font: 16px 'Old Standard TT', serif; line-height: 1.6; margin: 5px 3px; }
        @-webkit-keyframes h-pulsare { 0%, 100% { color: hsl(0,0%,100%); text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), 1px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%), 1px 0px hsl(240,100%,50%), 0px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px 0px hsl(240,100%,50%), 0px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%); } 50% { color: hsl(240,100%,90%); text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(210,100%,50%), -1px 1px hsl(210,100%,50%), 1px -1px hsl(210,100%,50%), -1px -1px hsl(210,100%,50%), 1px 0px hsl(210,100%,50%), 0px 1px hsl(210,100%,50%), -1px 0px hsl(210,100%,50%), 0px -1px hsl(210,100%,50%); } } @keyframes h-pulsare { 0%, 100% { color: hsl(0,0%,100%); text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), 1px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%), 1px 0px hsl(240,100%,50%), 0px 1px hsl(240,100%,50%), -1px 0px hsl(240,100%,50%), 0px -1px hsl(240,100%,50%); } 50% { color: hsl(240,100%,90%); text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(210,100%,50%), -1px 1px hsl(210,100%,50%), 1px -1px hsl(210,100%,50%), -1px -1px hsl(210,100%,50%), 1px 0px hsl(210,100%,50%), 0px 1px hsl(210,100%,50%), -1px 0px hsl(210,100%,50%), 0px -1px hsl(210,100%,50%); } }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="h">
    <h1>Конвертирование дат из григорианского календаря в юлианский и обратно.</h1>
    </div>
    <form name="converter">
        <div id="g">
        <label>по григорианскому календарю <span>(новый стиль)</span></label><br/>
        <select name="gwDay"></select><br>
        <select name="gDay"></select>
        <select name="gMonth"></select>
        <input type="number" name="gYear" id="gYear" min="-4713">
        <select name="gEra"></select><br/>
        <span>не ранее 24 ноября 4714 г. до н. э.</span><br/>
        <input type="button" name="gCalc" value="конвертировать в юлианский календарь">
        </div>
        <div id="u">
        <label>по юлианскому календарю <span>(старый стиль)</span></label><br/>
        <select name="jwDay"></select><br>
        <select name="jDay"></select>
        <select name="jMonth"></select>
        <input type="number" name="jYear" id="jYear" min="-4712">
        <select name="jEra"></select><br/>
        <span>не ранее 1 января 4713 г. до н.э.</span><br/>
        <input type="button" name="jCalc" value="конвертировать в григорианский календарь">
        </div>
        <div id="s">
        <button type="button" class="express" value="g_n_o_w_ce">сбросить на текущую дату</button>
        </div>
        <div id="b">
        <small>
        * Алгоритм действителен для всех (возможно, пролептических) григорианских дат не ранее 24 ноября 4714 до н. э. и юлианских дат не ранее 1 января 4713 до н. э.<br/></small>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Julian_day_number_calculation
    // The algorithms are valid for JDN >= 0, Gregorian >= 24.11.-4713, Julian >= 01.01.-4712
    function gregorianToJdn(d, m, y) {
        return tr((1461 * (y + 4800 + tr((m - 14) / 12))) / 4) +
               tr((367 * (m - 2 - 12 * tr((m - 14) / 12))) / 12) -
               tr((3 * tr((y + 4900 + tr((m - 14) / 12)) / 100)) / 4) + d - 32075;
    }
    function julianToJdn(d, m, y) {
        return 367 * y - tr((7 * (y + 5001 + tr((m - 9) / 7))) / 4) + tr((275 * m) / 9) + d + 1729777;
    }
    function jdnToJulianOrGregorian(j, to) { // to: true (julian), false (gregorian)
        var f = (to) ? (j + 1401) : (j + 1363 + tr((tr((4 * j + 274277) / 146097) * 3) / 4));
        var e = 4 * f + 3, h = 5 * tr((e % 1461) / 4) + 2;
        var d = tr((h % 153) / 5) + 1, m = ((tr(h / 153) + 2) % 12) + 1, y = tr(e / 1461) - 4716 + tr((14 - m) / 12);
        return { d: d, m: m, y: y };
    }
    function jdnToWeekDay(j) { return (j % 7) + 1; }
    function tr(n) { return n - n % 1; } // truncate (for integer division)
    // -- wiki end --
    var C = document.converter;
    // options
    var wdays = ['Понедельник','Вторник','Среда','Четверг','Пятница','Суббота','Воскресенье'];
    for (var o = '', i = 0; i < wdays.length; i++) o += '<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + wdays[i] + '</option>';
    C.gwDay.innerHTML = C.jwDay.innerHTML = o;
    for (var o = '', i = 1; i <= 31; i++) o += '<option value="' + i  + '">' + i + '</option>';
    C.gDay.innerHTML = C.jDay.innerHTML = o;
    var months = ['января','февраля','марта','апреля','мая','июня','июля','августа','сентября','октября','ноября','декабря'];
    for (var o = '', i = 0; i < months.length; i++) o += '<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + months[i] + '</option>';
    C.gMonth.innerHTML = C.jMonth.innerHTML = o;
    var eras = ['н. э.','до н. э.'], _eras = ['ce','bce'];
    for (var o = '', i = 0; i < eras.length; i++) o += '<option value="' + _eras[i] + '">' + eras[i] + '</option>';
    C.gEra.innerHTML = C.jEra.innerHTML = o;
    // -- options end --
    C.gCalc.onclick = function () {
        var gd = +C.gDay.value, gm = +C.gMonth.value, gy = historicalToAstronomical(+C.gYear.value, C.gEra.value);
        var jdn = gregorianToJdn(gd, gm, gy), wd = jdnToWeekDay(jdn), jd = jdnToJulianOrGregorian(jdn, true);
        var jy = astronomicalToHistorical(jd.y);
        C.gwDay.value = C.jwDay.value = wd, C.jDay.value = jd.d, C.jMonth.value = jd.m, C.jYear.value = jy.y, C.jEra.value = jy.e;
        onUpdateAll(jdn);
    };
    C.jCalc.onclick = function () {
        var jd = +C.jDay.value, jm = +C.jMonth.value, jy = historicalToAstronomical(+C.jYear.value, C.jEra.value);
        var jdn = julianToJdn(jd, jm, jy), wd = jdnToWeekDay(jdn), gd = jdnToJulianOrGregorian(jdn, false);
        var gy = astronomicalToHistorical(gd.y);
        C.gwDay.value = C.jwDay.value = wd, C.gDay.value = gd.d, C.gMonth.value = gd.m, C.gYear.value = gy.y, C.gEra.value = gy.e;
        onUpdateAll(jdn);
    };
    function initDate(c, d, m, y, e) {
        if (d + m + y == 'now') { var n = new Date(); d = n.getDate(), m = n.getMonth() + 1, y = n.getFullYear(); }
        C[c + 'Day'].value = d, C[c + 'Month'].value = m, C[c + 'Year'].value = y, C[c + 'Era'].value = e;
        C[c + 'Calc'].onclick();
        }
        function historicalToAstronomical(y, e) { // e: 'ce', 'bce'
        e = (y < 1) ? 'bce' : e;
        return ((e == 'bce') && y > 0) ? (1 - y) : y;
        }
        function astronomicalToHistorical(y) {
        var e = (y < 1) ? 'bce' : 'ce';
        return { y: (e == 'bce') ? -(y - 1) : y, e: e };
        }
        for (var ess = C.querySelectorAll('.express'), es, i = 0; i < ess.length; i++) {
        es = ess[i], es.onclick = Function.prototype.apply.bind(initDate, null, es.value.split('_'));
        }
        // Express-url format ...?C=D_M_Y_E
        var m = location.search.match(/(j|g)=(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(ce|bce)/);
        if (m) { initDate(m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4], m[5]); } else { initDate('g', 'n', 'o', 'w', 'ce'); }
        function onUpdateAll(jdn) {
        console.log('JDN:', jdn);
        console.assert(jdn >= 2299161, 'Proleptic: Gn < 15.10.1582 CE');
        console.assert(jdn >= 1704987, 'Proleptic: Jn < 01.01.45 BCE');
        console.assert(jdn >= 0, 'Invalid: Gn < 24.11.4714 BCE, Jn < 01.01.4713 BCE');
        }
        });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Поправил вопрос, но все же уточните, в чем именно вопрос, в определении количества дней, или в выводе в списки?

Comment: Kromster, и в определении количества дней для юлианского календаря, и в выводе в списке, другими словами в списках надо удалить опции с несуществующими днями 30, 31 февраля, 31 апреля и т.д.

Comment: В таком случае, это 2 отдельных вопроса, и задавать их стоит отдельно